# Crystal Report subreport "full filepath"

Tags: crystal-reports

How do you determine the "full-path" of a sub-report already inserted into a main report from "within" the main report itself i.e. how do I know where those sub-reports [being pointed to by the main report] are actually physically saved. Remember that those sub-reports were once physical reports located somewhere before they were inserted into the main report - hence logic says that CR ought to have a means of tracking this full-path.

This seems like a straightforward thing but for some reason I have noticed that its quite difficult to determine this from within the main report. Hence unless I designed the report myself, it can be quite difficult to know where those sub-reports are physically located. At best I have observed that its possible to determine the actual name of the sub-report from within the main report, still there seems to be no option to actually determine the "full-path" of the sub-report from "within" the main report.

I have come to realise that it practically helps to know where a physical sub-report is actually saved in case of disaster recovery - e.g. when a main report loses its sub-report design for no logical reason whatsoever [I have already experienced this problem myself].

Comment: +1 I have no idea how to get the imported subreport path, or even if it's possible to do so. My only thought is that you could backup new copies of the subreports and, if you're motivated, go so far as to replace the old copies with the new ones in the main reports.

Answer (score 0):

A sub-report exists in the same .RPT file as its container (parent).

** edit **

Looking at the SAP Crystal Reports 2011 Report Application Server Java SDK, I found an internal method that *might* work: ISubreportClientDocument.getReportURL().  It is located in the com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.report.application package.

While the .Net SDK has a similar object (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.SubreportObject), that object doesn't have a ReportURL property.

Comment: I think what Sysuser is asking is how to find out where a subreport was originally imported from. So if you "re-import subreport", the original file/path is used to reimport the report back into the main report... but it doesn't tell you where it is pulling from.

Comment: @Ryan ... you got what am trying to achieve perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the file path of a sub-report by copying the report to a different PC, disconnect the PC from the network and open report

Try to re-import the sub-report and an error message displaying the file path appears.

I can't take the credit as this link helped me solve it http://scn.sap.com/thread/3354250

Hope this helps